# How to filter rows in multiple columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, file-filter

I have multiple columns with some values. How can I filter rows with >=0.1 in Excel at a time?

```
    Name    A_NT.1  A_BPA.2 A_BaP.3 A_BPABaP.4  AT1_NT.5    AT1_BPA.6   AT1_BaP.7   AT1_BPABaP.8    CA_NT.9 A_NT.10
cg00000029  0.198605329 0.183343305 0.1799398   0.25618284  0.65682438  0.697011018 0.66559446  0.612064616 0.066735497 0.26899736
cg00000103  0.084859795 0.079312377 0.130624119 0.176744284 0.124958267 0.034326962 0.136574181 0.152639459 0.091380927 0.078150585
cg00000109  0.84287817  0.850985154 0.85685741  0.826090153 0.864274744 0.861868718 0.868841966 0.872549789 0.902866135 0.864917125
cg00000155  0.928850135 0.925733022 0.919547036 0.928490006 0.911981322 0.912145502 0.914123806 0.917595896 0.917322933 0.925490576
cg00000158  0.930643311 0.93841335  0.930477766 0.938036175 0.936979289 0.936501691 0.933797549 0.941721746 0.939412849 0.939155671
cg00000165  0.79474896  0.779440613 0.785663447 0.815538853 0.810547348 0.859685772 0.828302494 0.840452429 0.827981686 0.814584544
cg00000221  0.79120066  0.764425568 0.730947231 0.756862575 0.753541802 0.766724607 0.779293628 0.691737048 0.531770729 0.740580469
cg00000236  0.906530577 0.91577294  0.909523126 0.895882404 0.901508782 0.906403153 0.920356022 0.90194727  0.906969264 0.905285761
cg00000289  0.717840117 0.702938483 0.678406588 0.714949557 0.695086267 0.741477141 0.693400871 0.740824959 0.669505719 0.72294214
```

Comment: your question isn't clear, do you want to filter rows which contain only >=0.1 values?

Comment: Yes, I need rows with values >=0.1 from multiple columns at a time. I have changed my qtn now

Comment: So you want `Name` column to stay in place and only show the values for each `Name` row that are `>=0.1`. Is that correct? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to filter the table so that a row remains visible if *any* of its data contains a value >=0.1, the most straightforward way is to just add an additional column off to the right with some logic and then filter on that.

Assuming your data starts in `A1`, here's an array formula placed in column `L` that would accomplish this. Since it's an array formula, you'll need to confirm the formula with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, rather than just enter

`{=IF(SUM(IF(B2:K2>=0.1,1,0))>0,"show","hide")}`

This will return `show` if any of the data for that row has a value `>=0.1`, and return `hide` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments on clarification of the question - "Yes, I need rows with values >=0.1 from multiple columns at a time.", I understand you want to filter rows whose **ALL** columns are >=0.1, right?

Ideal is still to use array formula, which is similar to @Etheur's but simpler and more straight:

Suppose your data is at A1:K10, in cell L2, type formula `=AND(B2:K2>0.1)` then with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to be an array formula, to get true if **ALL** columns >=0.1, then fill down.

This formula is more simple and clear, since if you changed your mind, expecting **ANY** of the columns is >=0.1, you can simply change the `AND` to `OR`. In fact the result of @Etheur's is **ANY** of the column (You can see all rows are marked as `show`)

**Example Result** (orginal data omitted)

```
ALL>=0.1?   ANY>=0.1?
FALSE   TRUE
FALSE   TRUE
TRUE    TRUE
TRUE    TRUE
TRUE    TRUE
TRUE    TRUE
TRUE    TRUE
TRUE    TRUE
TRUE    TRUE
```